# Delete T SQL Statement with Parameters

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables:

1. ConnectionID (CID)
2. AuditLog (AL)

I would like to perform a delete statement to all rows in the `CID` table `where CID.UserID = AL.UserID`, if `CID.UserID` does not have a `AL.RecordDate` within the last 15 minutes.

What I've tried without success...

```
declare @15min datetime 
set @15min = dateadd(minute,-15,getdate())

Delete ConnectionID CID
inner join AuditLog as AL on CID.UserID = AL.UserID
Where AL.RecordDate < @15Min AND AL.UserID in CID.UserID
```

I am not an expert writing SQL statements so any advise would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to *not* delete any connection where it *does* have activity within the last 15 minutes? (as opposed to your attempt in your question which is closer to "delete *any* connection which had *any* activity more than 15 minutes ago").

Should be something like:

```
WITH RecentActivity as (
    SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM AuditLog
    WHERE RecordDate >= DATEADD(minute,-15,GETDATE())
)
DELETE FROM CID
FROM ConnectionID CID
       LEFT JOIN
     RecentActivity RA
       on
          CID.UserID=  RA.UserID
WHERE
    RA.UserID is NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `NOT EXISTS` like this.

```
declare @min15 datetime 
set @min15 = dateadd(minute,-15,getdate())
Delete CID FROM ConnectionID CID
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM AuditLog as AL
WHERE AL.UserID = CID.UserID
AND AL.RecordDate > @Min15
)
```

Comment: `EXISTS` is simple and fast. But `TOP 1` in `EXISTS()` has no gain on performance

Comment: @Eric - Yes, totally agree. it's just an old habit I have :)